# Crossfilter summing one column based on value in another column

Tags: crossfilter

My data looks like this:

```
Col1 | Col2
===========
12   | 0
2    | 13
23   | 0
4    | 0
16   | 12
```

Col 1 is a number and Col 2 are codes.  I want to sum the numbers in Col 1 where Col 2 = 0.  I have tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
var stemTotal = this.ndx.groupall().reducesum(function(d) 
    {if (d.col2 == 0) {return +d.col1;}});
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're very close! Just remember that in JavaScript a function always returns a value, even if you don't tell it to. The default return value is `undefined`.

And in this case, crossfilter is relying on the returned value in order to do the aggregation.

Since

```
undefined + 0 === NaN
```

you get a blank plot, probably.

Return zero in the case where you don't want the value to affect the sum, and you should be okay!

```
var stemTotal = this.ndx.groupall().reducesum(function(d) 
    {if (d.col2 == 0) return +d.col1; else return 0;});
```

Comment: I'm sorry I never answered your question Gordon.  I never received an email saying someone responded.  I did do something similar to this so thank you for answering.